# Infinite loop callbacks_poll React Native Debugger

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

I see this endless loop in the debugger network pane, both in Chrome and React Native Debugger using iOS Simulator and RN 0.49.5.

It basically shows and endlessly increasing number of network requests with the name `callbacks_poll`. I even see them when return null from my main App file. Tried clearing cache, resetting simulator, hard restart, etc. Any idea how to stop this?

[image]

Comment: In the meantime I found that the problem represents itself within XCode with this message `nw_connection_get_connected_socket` `Connection has no connected handler`. And I'm not the only one: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10027

Answer (score 0):

I just came across to the same error, with a bit of search found that the reason was the realm library.
If you do use realm, you can follow up the github issue here: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1538